# shell variable $? not working inside in an at heredoc

Tags: linux, bash, variables, at-utility

ubuntu 18.04
I need to get the value of the last command executed in an at heredoc :

### test.at.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
at now <<EOF
ls -la >> test.log;
RET=$?;
echo -e "\n----" >> test.log;
echo "exit code $RET" >> test.log;
EOF
```

I get in test.log only "exit code"

Even if I use bash inside at heredoc it doesn't work

### test.at.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
at now <<EOF
/bin/bash -c '
ls -la >> test.log;
RET=$?;
echo -e "\n----" >> test.log;
echo "exit code $RET" >> test.log;
'
EOF
```

Strangely enough this works, I get in test.log "exit code 0" :

### test.at.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
at now <<EOF
ls -la >> test.log;
echo "exit code $?" >> test.log;
EOF
```

This works ok

### test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -la >> test.log;
RET=$?;
echo -e "\n----" >> test.log;
echo "exit code $RET" >> test.log;
```

I get in test.log "exit code 0"

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: The contents of the here-doc are expanded. Try `<<'EOF'` to disable expansion.

Comment: great, that made it. Many thanks